# Call JavaScript/AJAX with a button without onClick function by his input name. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Got the next html code:

```
<form name="frm">
   <textarea class="textarea" name="textarea" id="textarea">
     <?php
        foreach ($textarea as $textareashow){
          echo $textareashow."\r\n";
        }?>
   </textarea><br><br>
   <input type="button" name="callbutton" value="Push button" id="execbutton" />
</form>
```

And the next JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#callbutton').click(function () {
     alert("HELLO!!!");
  });
});
```

What I want is to call the JavaScript function from his button input name. Is it possible? and from his input id? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#execbutton').click(function () {
       alert("HELLO!!!");
   });
});
```

Will work.

**Explanation:** `#` is used to select the element by **id** and `.` is used to select an element by **classname**. you are selecting element by name so you need to use the `$("input[name=callbutton]")`. If you are selecting any element by its property or attribute then you need to use it in `[]` brackets.  `[property_name=property_name_value]` like this.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you guys! After a while I realized that the call link to js/jquery was below the call link to my js/textareascript.js!!!!!!! that's why the script was not working. What a cock-up!

Comment: @user3321425 nice to hear from you and your hard work. My pleasure to help you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's possible. I've posted a `jsfiddle` below

You can use following `jQuery` selectors : `#id` and `input[name=something]` ( you don't need to use both of them )

To add a `click event` on a button ( in your case ) you can use `.click(function(){})`

So :

```
$(function(){
     $("#your_btn_id").click(function(){   // using selector by id
          // do something
     });

     $('input[name="your_btn_name"]').click(function(){  // using selector by name
         // do something
     });   
})
```

You can also combine selectors :

```
$(function(){
     $('#your_btn_id, input[name="your_btn_name"]').click(function(){   
          // do something
     });


     // or


    $("#your_btn_id").add('input[name="your_btn_name"]').click(function(){   
          // do something
     });
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgfnbc3e/1/)

Comment: Code and explanation *in the answer* is always better (JSFiddle to back up that it works) :)

Answer (score 5):

by input name use `input[name="callbutton"]` by id use the id notation #

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name="callbutton"],#textarea').click(function () {
    alert("HELLO!!!");    
  });
});
```